# Hiding ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

In my view point, i think, hiding ajax call from Google Chrome's console or firebug is impossible. However, I'm still curious how these guys on codefights do it. You may check [their leader board](https://codefights.com/leaderboard/?type=individual&period=total). Navigating to page 2, page 3... It really looks like AJAX calls but i cannot capture that call in firebug. There isn't any XHR call or js that contains the leader board data... I don't know how they send data to my browser. Does anyone know how they can do it? Is it an AJAX call or not? I really want to apply it to my current project but don't know where to start.

Comment: WebSockets; no mystery here.

Answer (score 1):

They use websockets. Nothing is hidden.

[image: screenshot]